# How to compute storage growth after some arbitrary code execution?

Tags: storage

I am working on implementing a new feature to limit the storage growth for a Substrate-based chain. As part of this feature, I need to compute the storage growth after executing arbitrary code. What is the most efficient way to measure the changes in storage consumption within the Substrate framework?